# Outlook VBA insert line of text

Tags: vba, outlook, ribbon

I'm trying to write a piece of code (vba) that inserts a single line in the email i'm composing (open e-mail item). The code below is a first step i took

**What works**

1. if I run the code directly from the module (development window), the text is inserted.

**What doesn't work**

1. If I add the a macro (vba) in my ribbon and try to run it, nothing happens. The code only seems to work directly form the module (Play button).

**What I want**

1. <strike>Run macro (vba) from ribbon in active/open item;</strike>
   Solution = A Module name can't contain a Macro of the same name.
2. Set font color to e.g. green;
3. Nice to have: insert text at bottom of page.

**Code:**

```
Sub InsertText()
Dim sText As String

sText = "Text to insert"


On Error GoTo ErrHandler
If TypeName(ActiveWindow) = "Inspector" Then
    If ActiveInspector.IsWordMail And ActiveInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
        ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeText sText
    End If
End If
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
Beep
End Sub
```

Comment: Point 1 solved: A Module name can't contain a Macro of the same name.

Comment: If you place a breakpoint on `Sub InsertText` and then press the button on the ribbon, does the code get run? and if it does run? what happens? does it go to the error handle? Does it not believe the active window and an Inspector? Does it not believe you use Word as the editor? There are a lot of variables here, the more information you could add the quicker we'll get the answer.

Comment: @Regenbui : Have you tried what was proposed by Gary? Does it work properly?

Answer (score 1):

When you are adding it to the ribbon, are you adding it to the mail item ribbon or outlook ribbon? This gets confusing so I'm going to use mostly pictures to describe it.

This is it added to the mail item ribbon and it worked fine: -
[image: Mail Item 'InsertText']

If I place the button on the Outlook bar pushing the button does not work: -
[image: Outlook 'InsertText']

This is because as soon as I push the button on the Outlook ribbon, the mail item is no longer the active window.

For confirmation, to add the button to to the mail item window, right click on the ribbon of a mail item and choose 'Customize the Ribbon...'
[image: Customize the Ribbon...]

Press the 'New Tab' button in the lower right, change 'Choose commands from:' to 'Macros' and click on the macro in question from the list below it. Finally, click the 'Add > >' and then 'OK'.
[image: Ribbon Customisation]